# What is the English translation for this picture

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate this
[image]

I tried to Google Translate it :
三屰戈巳市

But it didn't give me any satisfying translation.
I don't know if I typed it wrong or if Google Translate simply doesn't know what it means.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typed it wrong.

It's `三戦呂布`， means fight with [呂布](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BC_Bu) for three times.

It's a story also called as [三英戰呂布](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E4%B8%89%E8%8B%B1%E6%88%B0%E5%91%82%E5%B8%83), comes from the famous historical novel named `三国演义`([Romance of the Three Kingdoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_of_the_Three_Kingdoms)).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is actually written on an old incense burner that I have, there are effectively warriors on it. I don't know exactly how old it is, it's made of bronze and it's silver cloisonné.

Comment: And is there any specific english name for  三英戰呂布 ? (apart the name of the novel it comes from)

Comment: I can't find an official translation, though it means "Three heroes fight Lübu" in English.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise I can't find either. It's a special word for Chinese, because it's a famous story from the novel. Though it can be translated as `three heroes combating Lv Bu`, but I think it doesn't make sense for foreigners.